# What are the limitations of Blazor CascadingValue? Complex objects are not being passed

Tags: c#, blazor, cascadingparameter, cascadingvalue

I have an `IClipboardService` I was injecting into components, but as there is only ever one, I decided to try using a `CascadingValue` instead.

I recreated all this in a minimal test case. Just add these changes to a basic WebAssembly Blazor app:

I created a `CascadingClipboard.razor` component that looks like this

```
<CascadingValue Value="_clipboardService">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@inject ClipboardService _clipboardService

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

I also created a far simpler test `CascadingInt.razor` component with an `int` value

```
<CascadingValue IsFixed=true Value="_int">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public int _int { get; set; } = 123;
}
```

I wrapped the MainLayout.razor with both:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<CascadingClipboard>
    <CascadingInt>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>

        <main>
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
            </div>

            <article class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
    </CascadingInt>
</CascadingClipboard>
```

Added receiving `CascadingParameters` in `Index.razor`

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public CascadingClipboard _cascadingClipboard { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // BREAKPOINT HERE TO CHECK VALUES
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
}
```

The simple value is always present. The complex object is always `null`.

I have tried using an explicit assignment instead of injection, but no difference.

Is this simply a limitation of Blazor CascadingValues?

### More info:

The reason I tried this in the first place, is that my clipboard singleton needed to be initialised from local storage (to happily survive a refresh, or even returning later). Having a Cascading component makes that easy, but leaving the mechanics as a separate injectable service means I can still inject it into non-components (whereas Cascading only works with components). I now have a pattern for the best of both worlds.

Comment: You might try breakpointing OnRenderAsync, and waiting until after the first render.

Comment: Your ComplexObject is Injected, the sequence probably matters here. Try it w/o IsFixed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Breaking in OnAfterRenderAsync still shows null

Comment: @HH Same result with or without IsFixed. Also when I used a non-injected object, same null result.

Comment: I don't see where you pass the CascadingClipboard CascadingParameter.
Check the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like a bit of an idiot, but this may help someone else:

Assignment of a `CascadingValue` to a `CascadingParameter` works similar to `as` casting in C#. If the value types do not match it will be null.

If you look at my example, it had the same typo as in my original app, I was effectively trying to assign a `ClipboardService` object to a `CascadingClipboard` parameter.

It does not pay to trust Intellisence all the time :)

Comment: This is because Blazor attempts to do cascading parameter setting by matching type in the absence of a Name attribute. This is why I *always* use a Name with my CascadingValues/Parameters.

Comment: @Lex Even with the Name supplied (which I also tried), it will not match if the type is wrong, hence my original problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that it would work. I thought it would at least throw a runtime error if the types don't match, but after testing I see that it doesn't. That seems dumb, but I suppose they must have some reason not to raise an error.